Powershell parameter sets in other parameter sets
I have a function with the following parameter requirements:

There are no required parameters
$Credential can optionally be used with any other parameters, or no other parameters
$Title, $Username, and $SearchString cannot be used together
$DefaultObject and $AsPlainText can only be used with $Title or $Username
$DefaultObject and $AsPlainText cannot be used together

Below is what I have so far:
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'All')]
param (
    [PSCredential] $Credential,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
    [string] $Title,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
    [string] $Username,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Search')]
    [string] $SearchString,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'DefaultObject')]
    [switch] $DefaultObject,
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
    [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PlainText')]
    [switch] $AsPlainText
)

I have accomplished items 1-4 on the list, but I am struggling with item 5 to prevent $DefaultObject and $AsPlainText from being called simultaneously. Does anybody know how to prevent them from being used together? I have already tried creating a new ParameterSet for each of them, but that did not work.

The easiest way is to simply evaluate if ($DefaultObject -and $AsPlainText) then $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError in your function's body.

Your function's DefaultParameterSetName is 'All', but it is only available when 'none' of the parameters are used, so I expect you need to do some re-thinking about exactly what you are wanting and how it works.
But, based on what you described, this code should be fairly close to what you want.  It is important to understand that you need to use Mandatory to stress that certain parameters are mandatory for certain parameter sets:
Function Test-Params {
   [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'All')]
   param (
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
      [PSCredential] $Credential,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'TitleDO')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'TitleAPT')]
      [string] $Title,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsernameDO')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsernameAPT')]
      [string] $Username,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'Search')]
      [string] $SearchString,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'TitleDO')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsernameDO')]
      [switch] $DefaultObject,
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'TitleAPT')]
      [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ParameterSetName = 'UsernameAPT')]
      [switch] $AsPlainText
   )
   Write-Host $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
   switch ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName) {
      'All' {}
      'Title' {}
      'Username' {}
      'TitleDO' {}
      'UsernameDO' {}
      'TitleAPT' {}
      'UsernameAPT' {}
      'Search' {}
      Default {}
   }
}

These commands work, and comments show host output:
## Commands ##                                    ## Write-Host ##
Test-Params                                        # All
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle'                       # Title
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle' -DefaultObject        # TitleDO
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle' -AsPlainText          # TitleAPT
Test-Params -Username 'MyUsername'                 # Username
Test-Params -Username 'MyUsername' -DefaultObject  # UsernameDO
Test-Params -Username 'MyUsername' -AsPlainText    # UsernameAPT
Test-Params -SearchString 'My search text'         # Search

But all of these throw errors:
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle' -Username 'MyUsername'
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle' -SearchString 'My search text'
Test-Params -Username 'MyUsername' -SearchString 'My search text'
Test-Params -Title 'MyTitle' -Username 'MyUsername' -SearchString 'My search text'
Test-Params -SearchString 'My search text' -DefaultObject
Test-Params -SearchString 'My search text' -AsPlainText


This one works great, thanks a lot. I did not consider making multiple sets for 'Username 'and 'Title', but now I see it makes a lot of sense. Also, the 'All' set is in reference to the data returned in the function. If neither 'Title' nor 'Username' is used, it returns everything by default. Thank you for the great solution!

@AndrewDraper, you are welcome.  I spent about 2 weeks of free time around a year or so ago of just trying to get my head into how parameter sets work.  Once you get it, they're not that hard to do, but still very tricky to get right.  Start with only one or two parameters and get it to work the way you want, then add another, get it working, then add another, get it working, etc...  From experience, trying to build all parameters into a function at the same time is a nightmare.

I believe you just need to work your way from outside, to within. Instead of adding the parameter sets to $DefaultObject, add the parameter set to the other sets you want:
Function Test {
[CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [PSCredential] $Credential,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'DefaultObject')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
        [string] $Title,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'DefaultObject')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
        [string] $Username,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Search')]
        [string] $SearchString,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'DefaultObject')]
        [switch] $DefaultObject,

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Title')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'Username')]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'PlainText')]
        [switch] $AsPlainText
    )

}

help test

Produces:
    
SYNTAX
    Test [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Title <string>] [-AsPlainText]  [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Test [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Title <string>] [-Username <string>] [-DefaultObject]  [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Test [-Credential <pscredential>] [-Username <string>] [-AsPlainText]  [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Test [-Credential <pscredential>] [-SearchString <string>]  [<CommonParameters>]
    
    Test [-Credential <pscredential>] [-AsPlainText]  [<CommonParameters>]

